# What Does 8 Words of data mean?

Tags: caching

> 3, 180, 43, 2, 191, 88, 190, 14, 181, 44, 186, 253
>
> You are asked to optimize a cache design for the given references. There are 
>   three direct-mapped cache designs possible, all with a total
>   of 8 words of data: C1 has 1-word blocks, C2 has 2-word blocks, and C3
>   has 4-word blocks. In terms of miss rate, which cache design is the
>   best? If the miss stall time is 25 cycles, and C1 has an access time
>   of 2 cycles, C2 takes 3 cycles, and C3 takes 5 cycles, which is the
>   best cache design?

Okay, so that's the question I need to answer, and I am kind of confused. I understand how a cache works, and I understand how to calculate a miss and hit depending on the tag and index and what not. But what my question is, how many blocks am I using for these caches? I know that we're using 3 different caches with different word-blocks, so we can place more addresses into a block, for C2 for example we can place in 2 words, so 2 addresses. But what does it mean when it says "8 words of data"? I am having trouble understanding this question.

I assume that the more word-blocks there are, the better the hit rate, since we're able to store more addresses. But what does 8 words of data mean exactly, I guess that's my question?

Comment: I imagine words is related to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)

Answer (score 0):

Caches do not **only** contain data, there is information which has to be kept but isn't usable in the sense that it represents data which will be retrieved and operated with. With this, words of data means 4-byte-long continuous cache storage segments **meant for storing data**.

The **Index** and **Tag** fields are, for example, **not data**.

[image]
[image]

See [www.csbio.unc.edu/mcmillan/Media/Comp411S12PS6Sol.pdf](http://www.csbio.unc.edu/mcmillan/Media/Comp411S12PS6Sol.pdf) and https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/su07/cse141/cache-handout.pdf